# Stuck in Extracting only root element of JSON using Regex

Tags: java, json, regex

I've following JSON data:

```
{
    "a": {
          "b": "value" 
     },
    "c": {
         "a": {
              "b": "another value"
          }
     }
}
```

the order of the fields is not determined (i.e `b` can be above `a` in the example above). Now I only want to match the root element `a` and it's value.

What I've tried is the following regex:

```
(?:"c".*?})?.*"a":\s?.*?"b":\s?"?(.*?)"?[,}]
```

I've kept the non capturing group for field `c`. But the problem is that if there is no `b` field in entire JSON, for huge payloads, it takes too much steps to find out that there is no match in the payload (due to backtracking).

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/Ul0AxY/1) is a example of my actual payload, which took approx 9 seconds and 500K steps. in my actual payload on regex101, `a` = `file`, `b` = `size` and `c` = `event_actor`. So this would be very inefficient way to match JSON data.

So what I'm missing here? Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Note:** I want this type of regex for **Java**, therefore recursion is not supported in standard regex library.

Comment: This is not a regex job. Why not just get a JSON parser library and do `new JSONObject(payload).getJSONObject("file").get("size")`?

Comment: But I'm doing field extraction on IBM Qradar and for that regex usage is must.

Comment: This is not a regex job - an example, is that a value may have json within it, which means that the regex has to take into account of strings.  If you want to do it in regex then split it into 2 tries - one to find the single object, and then a second on the found object to get the right value.

Comment: Can you give an example @mksteve?

Comment: Any reason why this is not related to programming?